# Trace MS Access DB activity

Tags: debugging, ms-access

I have an Access application with a SQL server back-end, mixed with quite a few DB objects local to the Access app.  I've tried running SQL Profiler, but I got very little except a cryptic sp_execute 2,4288,4289,4290,4291,4292,4293,4294,4295,4296,4297.

I would like a trace tool that is local to the Access DB, so I also pick up any activity that doesn't go back to the SQL server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such facility within Access but, depending on your case, you could try these few things:

- Write a wrapper against SQL executables: that would mean replacing all calls to `Execute`, `OpenRecordset` etc within your VBA to an alternative version that would log the query.
  This isn't going to catch everything obviously but it could help.
- Move your local tables to another database and use ODBC to relink them to your original Access application. You can then use [ODBC's logging facilities](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzaii/rzaiiodbc58.htm).
  This could be the best altenative as it's fairly easy to setup for debugging.
  It's not the best solution for a production environment though as all your calls to local tables will in fact go through ODBC, but again, it's a temporary solution for debugging.
- Use [ShowPlan and ISAMStats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa188211.aspx#odc_4009c15_topic4) to [view how Jet/ACE interprets](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5064388.html) your queries and get other database activity stats.
  It's easy to setup by writing a key to the registry and you'll end-up with a log describing how your queries are analysed.
  It's more useful for optimisation than logging but again, it could help.

Comment: I like your second option most.  I'll give it a try tonight, thanks.

Comment: Oh yes, regarding your first option:  I don't have the VBA.

Comment: Option 2 seems ill-worded. The original question already said SQL Server was the data store, and I would assume that would mean using ODBC linked tables, as that's by far the easiest way to work with SQL Server data in an Access application. So all that was really needed was turning on ODBC logging.

Comment: @ProfK: if you're using Access you have VBA, though you may not be using it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Flextracer, a shareware, free for 30 days or so. My colleague here has just found this for us as we were going through a similar situation. Problem solved.

http://www.geardownload.com/development/flextracer-download.html

[]s,
Pedro Carneiro Jr.
pedrokarneiro@hotmail.com

Comment: What does that provide that ODBC logging lacks?